# Confused by Apache permissions

Tags: permissions, apache2

I know there's a wealth of Apache documentation, but I can't seem to find the answer.

With the default documentroot - `/var/www/html` - all is fine. Permissions are - `drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Feb 21 19:06 html/`. Permissions for the file within this are: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10918 Feb 21 19:06 index.html`

When I change the documentroot to `/mnt/mounty/testing` it no longer works ("Forbidden..."). Permissions for the directory look identical

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Jan 24 18:53 testing/
```

The html file within this has same owner / group and even more liberal permissions (yes I know not to 777 but this is a local test).

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root 39806 Jan 24 18:38 index.html*
```

What am I doing wrong? I've restarted Apache at every change. The parent folders of the original doc root and the new one are different - but surely this can't matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web content not reachable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959541/web-content-not-reachable)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166100/what-permissions-does-documentroot-directory-of-apache-server-requies-if-its-ou/1166141#1166141 is also a good candidate.

Comment: @vidarlo Those don't answer the question because this is not a permission issue. I believe you need to edit your conf file when changing the document root. [Here is an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/738527/167115).

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you can work around this by creating a simlink to the desired location from within the default document root (or by making the default document root a simlink to the desired location but it's been a while so I haven't tested this recently).

Comment: @vidarlo. Thanks for the links. The problem there is exactly the same - but the solution still does not work. The new path has exactly the same permissions as the old one but still no joy. I'll keep experimenting.